# Why do all groups show all users as members with Google Secure LDAP?

Tags: ldap, g-suite, sssd

After enabling and [configuring SSSD to use Google's Secure LDAP service](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/9089736?hl=en#sssd), when queried via `getent group`, all G-Suite groups show all G-Suite users as members:

```
$ getent group admin
admin:*:202851646:muru,user1,user2,....
$ getent group jira-users
admin:*:202851646:user5,user3,....
```

All users are present, but with different order.

Specifically, the Google LDAP logs show that SSSD uses the following query (site redacted):

```
(&(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=all,ou=Groups,dc=<site>,dc=com)(objectClass=posixAccount))
```

And indeed, if I use the same query with `ldapsearch`, all accounts are returned in the result.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is due to these lines in [G-Suite's recommended configuration for sssd](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/9089736?hl=en#sssd):

```
ldap_groups_use_matching_rule_in_chain = true
ldap_initgroups_use_matching_rule_in_chain = true
```

Remove these and the groups start showing members correctly (well, mostly, groups with the pseudo-entity "Everyone" as a member only show explicitly listed members).

---

Specifically, this is due to  `ldap_groups_use_matching_rule_in_chain`. From [`man sssd-ldap`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/sssd-ldap/sssd-ldap.5.en.html):

> ldap_groups_use_matching_rule_in_chain
>
> This option tells SSSD to take advantage of an Active
>   Directory-specific feature which may speed up group lookup operations
>   on deployments with complex or deep nested groups. In most common
>   cases, it is best to leave this option disabled. It generally only
>   provides a performance increase on very complex nestings.
>
> If this option is enabled, SSSD will use it if it detects that the
>   server supports it during initial connection. So "True" here
>   essentially means "auto-detect".
>
> Note: This feature is currently known to work only with Active
>   Directory 2008 R1 and later. See MSDN(TM) documentation[2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more
>   details.
>
> Default: False

And checking the MSDN docs:

> - 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941 **LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN**  This rule is limited to filters that apply to the DN. This is a special "extended" match operator that walks the chain of ancestry in objects all the way to the root until it finds a match.

And `1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941` is the rule used in the queries by sssd.

I don't LDAP queries well enough to judge which of SSSD's query or Google's LDAP service is broken. It isn't all that clear how I'm supposed to report such technical flaws in the help centre, so I haven't reported it to Google.